# Rxjava, how to block until it finishes?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit2, rx-java2

So I have 3 rest services to call, problem is, I need services 1 to finish before calling service 2 and I need service 2 to finish before calling service 3.

Because each time I need to pass data from the previous service to the next.

right now I'm chaining my tasks but I don't like it because method naming becomes quite massive

Example of service 1 ;

```
compositeDisposable.add(simpleRetrofitService.getInventaireDisponibleResultatDtos()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(this::callService2Then3ThenSaveThenGoToNextScreen,
                           this::logErrorAndDisplayPopup));
```

`callServiceOneThenTwoThenSaveThenGoToNextScreen()`

then define an other asynctask which calls `callService3ThenSaveThenFoToNextScreen()`

Any ideas?

Thanks.

## Edit : precision

Call1() will return an object containing a list of integer like [1, 2, 8, 132]
Then I have to call call2() for each integer.
And same thing for call3(), call2() gives me some values and I have to call Call3() for each values.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I'll assume your calls are `simpleRetrofitService.call1()`. `simpleRetrofitService.call2()` and `simpleRetrofitService.call3()`. I will also assume they are returning http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html

Then you can do some basic stuff like this (using http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html):

```
simpleRetrofitService.call1()
  .flatMap(r1 -> simpleRetrofitService.call2(r1))
  .flatMap(r2 -> simpleRetrofitService.call3(r2))
  .subscribeOn(...)
  .observeOn(...)
  .subscribe(...)
```

You don't really need AsyncTask at all.

---

Update as a response to question update:

Assuming your call returns list, you can do something like this (using http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flattenAsObservable(io.reactivex.functions.Function)):

```
simpleRetorfitService.call1()
  .flattenAsObservable(...)
  .flatMap(listItem -> simpleRetrofitService.call2(listItem)
  ...
```

Comment: this doesn't particularly `block` until the task is complete - instead it chains each request into the next, which will achieve the desired result. i was writing a similar answer to this so +1 from me :)

Comment: problem is if call1() returns [7, 8, 12, 15] I will have to call simpleRetrofitService.call2(xxx) 4 times with 7, 8, 12 and 15 in parameter

Comment: Then you have to provide details of your question. Apparently you're dealing with observables. More specific info is needed.